# time complexity of an algorithim quadratic for loop

Tags: time, complexity-theory

this is a pedusocode of an algorithm and im trying to figure out the time complexity and why. pedusodocde is very confusing.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoQIk.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoQIk.png)

I keep thinking its n^4logn but my friend says it n^4

Answer (score 0):

The cost `T(n)` can be written as in the figure:

[image: Cost]

The first sum is for the external cycle. As you can see, log n and n^2 are summed up and you only need to consider the higher order term.
I hope this will help